# Are case statements or function pointer arrays faster for special application in ANSI C?

Tags: c, switch-statement, function-pointers

In an ANSI C program, somewhere between 50 and 500 successive calls in somewhat random order to ten functions with identical call lists and return value are to be made thousands and up to millions of times. The actual number of function calls and their execution order are determined from random input data at launch, but will not change over the execution interval.

There seems to be some confusion as to whether switch statements or function pointer arrays would be faster. While the initial number of function calls and their call sequence are initially random at setup, they will remain constant throughout program execution. Are there any features of this situation that would make one method better than the other, and would there be specific compiler settings or directives that might help the compiler recognize this special case to improve performance of one method or the other? Using the GCC compiler in XCode.

Answer (score 3):

If your functions take a long time compared to the switch, it won't matter if you optimize the switch.  Measure, measure, measure.

If the functions take a short time compared to the switch, you get to choose between an virtually certain pipeline break for an indirect function call through an array (CPUs predict these quite badly [but read your assembly language manual on indirect jumps]), or (if well coded) a binary search to choose among your 10 or so functions (3-4 branches, any one of which cause a pipeline break).  The branch predictor in your CPU will try to guess the right branch directions based on actual statistics; it may get the misprediction rate down to zero for the common case.   If the order is only "somewhat" random, you can determine which calls have the highest frequency and build a discrimination network (a huffman tree) that biases the selection towards the highest probability function, then the next, etc, to minimize the average number of comparisons/pipeline breaks.

I suspect you'd do better if you inlined the function bodies into the switch inside your loop.  Done right, you won't have any explicit parameter passing, and that will help cut execution time.

Comment: These functions take a relatively long time compared to the switch. Not sure if they can be inlined as their call lists take pointers to structures and arrays. Need to check that out yet. Also have many, many other calls to very small specialty functions that could normally be inlined, except that the call order again cannot be determined until runtime. In many of these cases I can estimate the probability that each function will be called and maybe take some advantage of a huffman tree.

Comment: If the function calls take a long time compared to the switch/function-call-through-table, there's little point in optimizing the switch.  If you have lots of functions (you implied you had only 10), then a huffman tree probably will de-optimize; function pointers are what you need if there's lots of functions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your compiler, architecture, and possibly on the call signature.  This sounds like a good use case for just-in-time compilation (generate some source code, call `gcc` and `ld` on it, `dlopen` the resulting .so file, `dlsym`, and call).

Comment: If you're really concerned about performance, executing `gcc` and `ld` before loading the .so file will likely hurt the performance of thousands of function calls, and just break even on millions, since disk is so slow.  However, generating the machine code yourself and dropping it into [a memory-mapped executable page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (**as long as you have proven that this doesn't present a security risk**) will likely be much faster.  Note that the doc link I gave is for Linux, but I would expect OS X to have a similar API.

Comment: @Adam: Yes, manually creating the machine code will be faster.  But it is also a lot more work, and totally non-portable.

Comment: If hardcoding direct calls to functions would significantly reduce runtime, it would be easy to provide a processor that generates a runtime algorithm containing the hardcoded calls and then compile and link it before execution. Users will tolerate the delay if it buys them time downstream.